# How to save multiple lines in SQL Server 2008 from text area?

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

How to save multiple lines in SQL Server 2008 from text area??

```
<textarea runat="server" rows="5" cols="70"  id="commentarea"  
          name="commentarea"  style="margin-left: 197px" ></textarea>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 287px" 
            Text="Comment" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

C# code:

```
ConnectionStringSettings pubs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"];

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(pubs.ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CommentTable (Comment) values( '" + commentarea.InnerText+"')";

connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

dont do this ,use parametrized queries

```
ConnectionStringSettings pubs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"];
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(pubs.ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CommentTable (Comment) values(@Text )";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", acommentarea.InnerText);
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: ok thanks  i know that but when i insert multiline in text area , the database table cant save multiline if th data type is varchar

Comment: <HTML>
 <textarea runat="server" rows="5" cols="70"  id="commentarea"  name="commentarea"  style="margin-left: 197px" ></textarea>

  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 287px" 
                Text="Comment" onclick="Button1_Click" />
            <br />
</HTML>

Comment: @Buzz: `TEXT` is **deprecated** since SQL Server **2005** - use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead.

Comment: thanks,but in dont know how to read multi line from text area,I coded it sucessfully but the data stored as single line when i read it from text area.

Comment: if you want html formatting then use any HTML editor like this one-http://www.tinymce.com/